# I don't understand the difference in meaning of ようにする and ようになる in this particular sentence

Tags: grammar, transitivity

朝早く起きられるようになりました。apposed to 朝早く起きられるようにしました。

I understand that the first sentence is intransitive and the second is transitive but I don't understand the difference in meaning

From my understanding they both mean 'I was able to make a habit of waking up early'

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 朝早く起きられるようになりました。
>   I reached the point where I can wake up early in the morning.

e.g. I used to be no good at getting up early, but after a few months discipline I don't have a problem anymore.

> 朝早く起きられるようにしました。
>   I made sure I can get up early in the morning.

e.g I set my alarm clock for 5:00 am.

Comment: or, in other words, ようになる in this case is something that "came to be" passively, and ようにする in this case is something that was "made to be" actively.