# ようにしよう vs ようになった。

Tags: meaning

> 1. 机の位置を変えて、仕事中でも外の景色が見えるようにしよう。

vs

> 2. 机の位置を変えたので、仕事中でも外の景色が見えるようになった。

Can someone explain what the difference between 1 and 2 are?

For me at first glace, 1 is saying something like since I CHANGED MY DESK POSITION, LETS ALL LOOK OUTSIDE.  Am I right ?

For 2 it seems like the desk positioned was changed for the purpose of the worker to be able to look outside?

So in 1, did the worker change their desk position in order to look outside and in 2 someone else changed their desk position for the worker to look outside? Or am I wrong on both fronts?

Comment: Double check the meaning of 見える

Comment: Related: [I don't understand the difference in meaning of ようにする and ようになる in this particular sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60755/43676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicaly sentence 1 is expressing **the will** of changing the desk position so it is possible to see the outside view while working.

Whereas sentence 2 is putting the stress on **the consequence** "it has become possible to see the outside view while working" because one has changed the desk position.